# CSS problem with safari address bar on iOS 15

Tags: scroll, modal-dialog, ios15

After updating iphone to iOS 15 I'm facing strange issue. I have custom modal which is getting shown/hidden just by adding CSS class. As soon as I show modal (when address bar is visible) and try to scroll within modal this modal get's closed. But when I first scroll down on page (address bar is hidden) then open modal I can scroll within modal without problem. Same happen when scrolling up within modal. That means address bar is causing this issue.
In other browsers there is no problem.
Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Ok found the problem. Since iOS 15 safari address bar collapse calls window.resize method. That was the issue...

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: @JonasPraem just needed to remove window.resize event and it's  method

Comment: Thanks, this helped me find the cause of my problem quickly